# At checkout if the cart product(s) match specific id(s) do something - WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Trying to display a message at checkout if the cart product(s) match specific id(s).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation' , 'product_specific_message', 10, 2 );
function product_specific_message( $data ) {

    $product_ids = ['111342', '111347'];
    
    $p = wc_get_product( $product_ids );

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    
    $product              = $values['data'];

    if ( $product ) {

    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids ) ) {

          echo "test";

                 
              }
           }
        }

    return $data; 
    
}
```

This doesn't work and allows the product(s) to complete checkout.

I've tried :

```
$product_id           = $values['product_id'];
    
$variation_id         = $values['variation_id'];
    
$products_ids_array[] = $values['product_id'];
```

With this :

```
if ( $product_ids === $product->get_id() ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this first function for a handful of other functions. So you could throw this in your functions.php file and then anytime you need to evaluate if there's "X" in the cart (using some other hook), you just pass the ids into the function. I think I got your values correct, but double-check them.

Also, in the first line of your code, you're telling the add_action to be "priority" 10 and that you are expecting 2 attributes (but you're only passing one) so you don't need the "2". You may need to adjust the priority based on where the message spits out.

And your action will typically not "return" anything, (that's mostly filters) so your echo should be just fine.

```
function woo_custom_product_is_in_the_cart($chosen_ids){
    //create an empty array
    $cart_ids = array();
    // Find each product in the cart and add the ID to the $cart_ids array
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
        $cart_product = $values['data'];
        $cart_ids[]   = $cart_product->id;
    }
    // If one of the special products are in the cart, return true.
    if (!empty(array_intersect($chosen_ids, $cart_ids))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'product_specific_message', 10);
function product_specific_message()
{
    if ( is_checkout() ) :
        $chosen_ids = array(111342,111347);
        if (woo_custom_product_is_in_the_cart($chosen_ids)) :
            echo 'neato message here';
        endif;
    endif;
}
```